# WPF Checkbox IsChecked property not working when msi is deployed in VM

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have a checkbox which hides the excel sheet on uncheck and shows on checked. Below is my code:

Xaml:

```
<CheckBox Foreground="White" x:Name="chkShowExcelPanel" Content="Show Excel Sheet" Checked="AdjustGrid" Unchecked="AdjustGrid" IsChecked="{Binding Path= _ShowExcel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

MVVM:

```
private bool _showExcel;
        public bool _ShowExcel
        {
            get { return _showExcel; }
            set
            {
                _showExcel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("_showExcel");
            }
        }
```

Its working Fine on the local machine but as soon as I run it on VM I can't see it's checked unless I get the mouse on it.

One thing which bothers me is that my get accessor is not enabled i.e.it says Accessor '_ShowExcel' is never used.

Comment: fix your `OnPropertyChanged("_showExcel");`  capital 'S'  ==>   `OnPropertyChanged("_ShowExcel");`

Comment: VM is a Virual Machine ? if yes, I think your issue is related to your video refresh rate

Comment: I Changed it to 'S' but still it's not working.

Comment: Yes, its my virtual machine. But what do you mean by video refresh rate?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the VM you are using? I.e. is it VirtualBox, VMware,...? And what environment is it hosting?

Comment: @UnNamed basically means that your software is correct, but the information in the video of your VM is not being updated as it should be, try the following to see if this really works, try moving the program window instead of hovering over the checkbox

Comment: It's Windows Server 2012r2.

Comment: @Celso Livero moving program windows didn't help.